# Stopping DFS after executing once

Tags: c++, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

I am having an adjacency list and I created a graph with that. Now I wanted to carryout DFS but wanted to stop as soon as I visit the first neighbor of a node and then print all the elements corresponding to that neighbor node.

Can someone please help me here - how do I stop DFS based on above condition

Comment: `if(condition) return;` You should be much more specific and provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to get any meaningful answer

Comment: Like @Drop says, you could set up a boolean, check the condition you are seeking and return. I am curious why you want to do that. What's your use case?